# Navigtion usercontrols return value wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls, navigation

I am looking for a system which let me navigate between usercontrols and return me values.

For example.. I have a Customer List UserControl with a "Add New Customer" Button.

If I press "Add New Customer" Button, my application must navigate to "Add New Customer" User Control.

When I add the Customer, I want back to "Customer List" User Control with the new Customer created.

I am looking for something similar to:

```
//Command in ViewModel Customer List User Control

private void AddCustomerCommand(object parameter)
{

//Navigate to Customer Add User Control and wait for result

EntityCustomer customer = somethingApplicationCoreClass.Show(Consts.Customer_Add);

   //I returned to my Customer List User Control
   if(customer !=null)
   {

      //I add the new customer created in my ObservableCollection of CustomerList User Control
      clientsCollection.Add(customer);
   }
}
```

I saw like navigate between UserControls and Pages and I saw like to return values using events. But I like me know if it's possible do it most clean. I think that if I can receive the value without events it's better.

I don't know where investigate. I was looking in google and this page, but I didn't see nothing.

I hope you can help me. And sorry by my english, I'm spanish and I try write the better possible. Thanks for your time. : )

Comment: Do you want it all to be in a single window or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Hi VMaleev, thanks for you response and time. Yes I want this in a single window.